# Populating a magento order form with custom attributes

Tags: php, magento

I created an attribute set and added a `shirtsize` attribute with the options Small, Medium, and Large.

On template/catalog/product/view.phtml, I'm populating a drop down with

```
<?php
$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'shirtsize');
foreach ($attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions(true, true) as $instance) {
  echo '<option>' . $instance['label'] . '</option>';
}
?>
```

Now, I need to get this data to post with the `product_addtocart_form` form so I can save their selection with the order and access it on the checkout page / receipt.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: have you looked to the default template and observed how things are handled there?

Comment: When I apply the default template, I do not see the custom attributes I added in the backend.  I'm not sure if these are supposed to show up or if I need to manually display them (as I did).

Comment: they need to show up if configured correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you appear to be trying to do is to create a configurable product. To do this, and have the customer able to select the correct size in the catalog, is to add a "Configurable Product" typed item, and add the "Simple Product" type items underneath it (one for each size). When you make the configurable product viewable in the catalog, Magento will automatically provide the sizing options and manage the technical aspects of buying the products in each size.

If you don't want to make so many products, you're looking more at a Product Option on a product, which is not added as an attribute. Instead, add it to your product in the edit form, and again Magento will manage selection / storing of this option.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks!  I needed to use Product Options instead of a configureable product.  I now see my drop downs generated from Magento.